# How to animate custom cell header ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, header, cell

I'm new to iOS. I'm using storyboard for UI development. I created  a custom header cell with a label and activity loader. now I want to animate the header cell of section-1 on switch on off. I tried enough but i didn't able to do that.
But when i create a custom header for only section-1 then cell was animating. But i want to re-use that cell for all the section. when i doing this i.e when i created a custom header for two section then cell is not animating and even activity loader is also stop animating. when i create cell header for two section the frame value return (0,0,600,44)and (0,0,600,44) but when created for section-1 only it return (0,98,383,44), why in this case width is less and why header created for two section is not animating.
Please help me.

Here is the code snippet:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bluetoothCell"];
UISwitch *addswitch=nil;


   if (addswitch==nil)
   {
     addswitch=[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectZero)];
   }

  if (indexPath.section==0)
 {
      if (indexPath.row==0)
     {
        cell.accessoryView=addswitch;
        [addswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(bluetoohSwitchClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged ];
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Bluetooth";
    }

}
else if (indexPath.section==1) {

    cell.textLabel.text=@"bluetooth devices";
    cell.accessoryView=nil;
}


 return cell;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return 44.0;
}

 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  HeaderTableViewCell *customheader;
  NSLog(@"section.. %ld",(long)section);

      customheader=[ tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headercell"];
       self.customheader=customheader;


customheader.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
if (section==0) {
    customheader.activityloader2.hidden=NO;
    customheader.tag=0;
    NSLog(@"section %ld,%@",(long)section,customheader);

} else if(section==1) {
    customheader.activityloader2.hidden=NO;
    customheader.tag=1;
    NSLog(@"sections %ld,%@",(long)section,customheader);
}

 return customheader;
 }

 -(void)bluetoohSwitchClicked:(id) sender
{
   UISwitch* switchControl = sender;
   if ([switchControl isOn])
  {
    self.onoffswitch=@"ON";
    [switchControl setOn:YES animated:YES];


  }
 else
  {
     self.onoffswitch=@"OFF";
    [switchControl setOn:NO animated:YES];
 }
 [self bluetoothStatechanged:[self.onoffswitch isEqualToString:@"ON"]?YES:NO];

  }

   -(void)bluetoothStatechanged:(BOOL)on
  {

HeaderTableViewCell* customheader=(HeaderTableViewCell *)[self tableView:self.maintableview2 viewForHeaderInSection:1];

__block CGRect frame=customheader.frame;
NSLog(@"bluetoothStatechanged 2 %f,%f,%@",frame.origin.y,frame.size.height,customheader);


if (on==YES)
{

    [customheader.activityloader2 startAnimating];

    customheader.alpha = 0.0 ;

    frame.origin.y-=frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"frame1 %@",customheader);
    customheader.frame=frame;

    NSLog(@"frame %@",customheader);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2f animations:^{
        customheader.alpha = 0.1 ;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
            frame.origin.y+=frame.size.height;
            customheader.frame=frame;
            customheader.alpha = 1.0 ;

        }];
    }];

}
else
{

    [customheader.activityloader2 stopAnimating];
    customheader.alpha = 1.0 ;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        customheader.alpha = 0.9 ;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

            frame.origin.y-=frame.size.height;
            customheader.frame=frame;
            customheader.alpha = 0.0 ;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            frame.origin.y+=frame.size.height;
            customheader.frame=frame;
        }];
    }];


  } 
}
```

But when if I change the cellForRowAtIndexPath function like bellow, then it create the header in second section i.e section-1 and also activity indicator is also working but header is not created in first section i.e section-0.

```
  -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:          (NSInteger)section
  {
    HeaderTableViewCell *customheader;
   NSLog(@"section.. %ld",(long)section);

   if(self.customheader==nil)
{
    customheader=[ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headercell"];
   self.customheader=customheader;
    }else
   {
   customheader=self.customheader;
    }

     ...// all is same as written above
     }
```

Comment: Try the IRC channel of iOS, you might get some help there.